# ETW events in Azure diagnostics (SDK 2.5) are logged with incorrect / missing schema

Tags: azure, etw, azure-diagnostics

I upgraded to Azure SDK 2.5 and switched to semantic logging with `EventSources`. 
Logging works locally with a custom `EventListener`.

When deployed, logs are written to a storage table, but only the `EventId`, `Pid`, `Tid` etc. are populated, the really interesting fields (Message, Task, Keyword, Opcode) are left blank.

The diagnostics infrastructure log is full of errors with regards to ETW, but I don't know what to make of them:

```
Failed to load backup EventSource manifest file C:\Resources\{13b7ec61-6424-d4d3-9972-a83e58d8d6bb}\directory\f71b19461fcf494d89d3717b3a13cadf.    something.WorkerRole.DiagnosticStore\WAD0103\Configuration\EventSource_Manifest_fe06b63d-39aa-5419-0529-18c4dacf4f68_Ver_20.backup.xml;  

EventSource    events will be logged without a proper schema until provider sends the manifest packets

Load manifest file failed for C:\Resources\{13b7ec61-6424-d4d3-9972-a83e58d8d6bb}\directory\f71b19461fcf494d89d3717b3a13cadf.something. WorkerRole.   DiagnosticStore\WAD0103\Configuration\EventSource_Manifest_fe06b63d-39aa-5419-0529-18c4dacf4f68_Ver_20.xml

Failed to manage manifest version for file C:\Resources\{13b7ec61-6424-d4d3-9972-a83e58d8d6bb}\directory\f71b19461fcf494d89d3717b3a13cadf. something.   WorkerRole.DiagnosticStore\WAD0103\Configuration\EventSource_Manifest_fe06b63d-39aa-5419-0529-18c4dacf4f68_Pid_3436.xml

Failed to process EventSource manifest event GUID:fe06b63d-39aa-5419-0529-18c4dacf4f68, event id:0xFFFE

Change in the number of events lost since the last sample: EventsCaptured=2 EventsLogged=1 EventsLost=0
```

I do not use a manifest file and specify the `EventSource` via class / attribute name:

```xml
<EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration scheduledTransferPeriod="PT3M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Information" provider="something.Core">
  <DefaultEvents eventDestination="CoreEvents" />
</EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration>
```

I must be missing something, but I do not know what.

The remaining diagnostic services all work (infrastructure logs, performance counter etc.).
The `EventId` that is being logged is the correct one, but all the important information of the log is missing, I suppose because of an incomplete configuration?

---

**Edit:** here is my `EventSource` code. I won't post the entire thing because it's quite large. I use another type that calls the EventSource methods and handles formatting of parameters (if the source is enabled in that level). Most method arguments are of type `string`, there are no objects or other complex types passed around (that handles the other type).

```cs
[EventSource(Name = "something.Core")]
public sealed class CoreEventSource : EventSource {
    private static readonly CoreEventSource SoleInstance = new CoreEventSource();

    static CoreEventSource() {}
    private CoreEventSource() {}

    public static CoreEventSource Instance {
        get { return SoleInstance; }
    }

    public static EventKeywords AllKeywords = (EventKeywords)(-1);

    public class Keywords {
        public const EventKeywords None = (EventKeywords)(1 << 1);

        public const EventKeywords Infrastructure = (EventKeywords)(1 << 2);
        [...]
    }

    public class Tasks {
        public const EventTask None = EventTask.None;

        // generic operations
        public const EventTask Create = (EventTask)11;
        public const EventTask Update = (EventTask)12;
        public const EventTask Delete = (EventTask)13;
        public const EventTask Get = (EventTask)14;
        public const EventTask Put = (EventTask)15;
        public const EventTask Remove = (EventTask)16;
        public const EventTask Process = (EventTask)17;
    }

    [Event(1, Message = "Initialization of {0} failed: {1}.", Level = EventLevel.Critical, Keywords = Keywords.Infrastructure)]
    public void CriticalInitializationFailure(string component, string details, string exception) {
        this.WriteEvent(1, component, details, exception);
    }

    [Event(2, Message = "[Role '{0}'] Startup: {1}", Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Infrastructure)]
    public void RoleStartup(string roleName, string message) {
        this.WriteEvent(2, roleName, message);
    }

    [Event(3, Message = "[Role '{0}'] Stop failed: {1}.", Level = EventLevel.Error, Keywords = Keywords.Infrastructure)]
    public void RoleStopFailed(string roleName, string details, string exception) {
        this.WriteEvent(3, roleName, details, exception);
    }

    [Event(4, Message = "An unhandled exception occurred.", Level = EventLevel.Critical, Keywords = Keywords.Infrastructure)]
    public void UnhandledException(string exception) {
        this.WriteEvent(4, exception);
    }

    [Event(5, Message = "An unobserved exception occurred in a faulted task.", Level = EventLevel.Critical, Keywords = Keywords.Infrastructure)]
    public void UnobservedTaskException(string exception) {
        this.WriteEvent(5, exception);
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code of your EventSource implementation?

Comment: @schadr I updated my question with (part of) the implementation. I already had some fun with incorrect Keywords values and the like –  is there some way I can verify whether the implementation is valid,  especially considering future developments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there were quite a few problems with my `EventSource`. The first thing I'd recommend to anyone working with ETW is to use the [Microsoft TraceEvent Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/) from NuGet, even if you use `System.Diagnostics.Tracing`, because it comes with a tool that will verify your `EventSource` code and notify you about problems.

I had to fix the following:

- `EventSource` names must not contain a period `.`
- Task/Opcode pairs must be unique within an `EventSource`
- One must not declare a `None` field in a custom Keywords or Tasks enumeration

Hope this is of some use to anyone who encounters a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that should be taken care of (which fixed our case)
 - EventSources should only have a Name or a Guid, not both.

In our case, having both caused
 - The EtwEventSourceProvider to not log anything
 - The EtwEventManifestProvider to log the same way you outlined, with empty data points.